Formula for the Sum of the Reciprocals of the Imaginary Parts of the Nontrivial Zeroes of the Riemann Zeta Function
Assume the Riemann Hypothesis, so that every nontrivial zero $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function looks like $\rho = \frac{1}{2} + \gamma i$. Let $T > 0$ be an integer. On page 51 of Appelgren and Tikkanen's The Riemann Hypothesis and the Distribution of Primes, we are told that
$$\sum_{|\gamma| \leq T}\frac{1}{|\gamma|} = \sum_{t = 1}^T [N(t) - N(t-1)]\frac{1}{t}$$
where $N(t)$ denotes the number of nontrivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function whose imaginary part lies within height $t$ on the imaginary axis. Why is this equality true? I do not see how the actual imaginary parts of the zeroes are being accounted for on the righthand side.

The first non-trivial zero has imaginary part $\gamma_1\simeq 14.134$ so plugging $T=15$ in your formula yields $\frac{1}{\gamma_1}=\frac{1}{15}$ which is false.

Appelgren and Tikkanen's article is here and the equality is indeed questionable

(let's add that it is a fine approximation since for $T\le 200$ the absolute error is less than $0.013$)

So how do we correct the statement?
